# Facing an issue in accessing a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My postgres table is having a column name called "**class**". On accessing the relevant **model** to this **table** am getting this error: **(Object doesn't support #inspect)**. This all issue is because of using a reserved word as a column name.

Is there any **solution** to this to make the model accessible without modifying/renaming the column name of the table? Am using Rails5. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your issue realte to a reserved word so you need to look around posgres more than rails

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with a column named `class`, it seems to mess up ActiveRecord's internals somehow. Thus I think you'll need to rename that column to e.g. `klass`.

Or, in case you can't change DB schema, create an updatable view on top of it, where you name the column as you please.